# Сайт не уведомляет о редактировании комментариев

Tags: предложение, правки, комментарии

В последнее время у меня как-то часто бывает, что в ответ на комментарии задам вопрос, сижу жду ответа — а его нет, через полчаса обновляю страницу — оказывается, комментарий был отредактирован и ответ на мой вопрос давным-давно есть в этом самом отредактированном комментарии, просто сайт об этом никак не уведомил. Раз уж сайт уведомляет о новых комментариях (строчкой «Показать ещё N комментариев»), то хотелось бы, чтоб уведомлял как-нибудь и об отредактированных, чтоб кнопку F5 не ломать)

Comment: Это не сюда, это на Meta.SE. Это по сути багофича движка.

Comment: а мне казалось - при редактировании тоже появляется полоска - новые комментарии или как-то так